# How can multiple Imported classes call each others methods?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have this index.js file:

```
import GameController from './Controllers/GameController'
import LandController from './Controllers/LandController'

const GAME = new GameController();
const LAND = new LandController();
```

And in this class, I want to call a function every second using setInterval:

```
export default class GameController {
  tickCount = 0;

  tick = setInterval( () => {
    this.Tick()
  }, 1000);

  Tick () {
    LAND.updateLand();
    this.tickCount++;
  }

}
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: GAME is not defined
```

I'm new to webpack, I had this working in vanilla javascript but I'm still learning, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

EDIT:
Updated GameController class based on bravo's answer, however now I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: LAND is not defined
```

How can I make it so multiple classes can call each others methods?

Comment: since `GAME` is not a global variable, then of course it won't be accessible in Gamecontroller module - also, you are referencing an instance that wouldn't exist yet

Comment: Since `LAND` is being declared outside the `GameController` module, the `GameController` class won't be able to access it. If the methods of `GameController` and `LandController` depend on each other, why not use class inheritance or composition, or simply merge them together? Please detail the dependency relations between the two classes, and your requirements so that we can suggest a design rework.

Answer (score 3):

You started using modules and classes, so you are moving to OOP (Object Oriented Programming). This means that you should forget about scripting, where you declare globals, everything manipulates everything, and start reasoning in a structured, hierarchical, and isolated fashion (where you have objects responsible for specific tasks).

You started properly by understanding what `isolation` is. You created an autonomous class to control the land. Then you need a game controller, which controls the land (and anything else, but we will come back to this lather).

Follow the reasoning; `Game` controls `Land`, in `OOP` this would translate in either `Game` receives `Land` or `Game` creates `Land`. Which of two to choose depends on the specific use case.

###### `Game` creates `Land`

```
// ./Controllers/GameController.js
import LandController from './Controllers/LandController'

export default class GameController {
  tickCount = 0;
  land = new LandController();

  intercal = setInterval(this.onTick.bind(this), 1000);

  onTick () {
    this.land.updateLand();
    this.tickCount++;
  }

}
```

```
// index.js
import GameController from './Controllers/GameController'

const GAME = new GameController();
```

Here you can see how `Game` creates `Land`, this is useful but reduces your access to the `Land` constructor (assuming you do not want to change `Game` to configure land)

###### `Game` receives `Land`

```
// ./Controllers/GameController.js

export default class GameController {
  tickCount = 0;
  land;

  constructor(land) {
    this.land = land;
  }

  intercal = setInterval(this.onTick.bind(this), 1000);

  onTick () {
    this.land.updateLand();
    this.tickCount++;
  }

}
```

```
// index.js
import GameController from './Controllers/GameController'
import LandController from './Controllers/LandController'

const LAND = new LandController();
const GAME = new GameController(LAND);
```

Here you have access to both constructors and your code is more maintainable. `Game` is not concerned about `Land` (*what is*, *what it has in* or *where it came from*) as long as it has a method `updateLand()` that has to be called at an interval.

###### More than land

The second solution allows you to implement a more versatile `Game`. Assume your `Land` has a method called `update()` rather than `updateLand()`.

```
// ./Controllers/GameController.js

export default class GameController {
  tickCount = 0;
  children;

  constructor(children) {
    this.children = children;
  }

  intercal = setInterval(this.onTick.bind(this), 1000);

  onTick () {
    this.children.forEach(c => c.update());
    this.tickCount++;
  }

}
```

And then you can go beyond `Land`, maybe have a `Character` or more `Land`, or anything else.

```
// index.js
import GameController from './Controllers/GameController'
import CharController from './Controllers/CharController'
import LandController from './Controllers/LandController'

const LAND1 = new LandController();
const LAND2 = new LandController();
const CHAR = new CharController();
const GAME = new GameController([ LAND1, LAND2, CHAR ]);
```

This is how you can start reasoning to structure your OOP software properly; objects that are concerned about tasks and other objects.

- When an object is not concerned about another object it should not have access to it (so no globals)
- When an object is responsible for another object it should have direct access (receive them from the constructor or a setter) or directly instantiate them (create them).

Comment: So you are saying that using Object Oriented Programming is *reasoning properly*?

Comment: @GuerricP. If I understood where our misunderstanding came from; that was an unfortunate sentence (Derived from Italian), reading it again from your perspective made me laugh too. Let me fix it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make the instances global, which I would not recommend because there are normally are better methods then using global variables, you should setup the variables in the window object

```
window.yourNamespace = {};
window.yourNamespace.game = new GameController();
window.yourNamespace.land = new LandController();
```

Then you can access both objects everywhere you like with

```
window.yourNamespace.game
window.yourNamespace.land
```

Answering your question about a non global solution:

I can only guess what your application will do but it sounds like a game. So GameController should be the main class. From this class you should instantiate all other classes like the LandController(). In that case you can access the LandController of course from the GameController. If you need an object in a class you should give the object as an parameter. E.g.

```
Class GameController()
{
    landController = new LandController();

    … here all needed methods for the class …

    // Example if you need LandController in an other Class
    exampleMethod()
    {
        Let otherClass = new OtherClass(this.landController);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I were to not make them global, could you point me in the direction of a better solution please? :)

Comment: I have modified my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

We may use a constructor for that.

```
export default class GameController {

  tickCount = 0;
  tick = null;

  constructor() {
        this.tick = setInterval(() => {
        this.Tick()
  }, 1000);

  }

  Tick () {
    LAND.updateLand();
    this.tickCount++;
  }

}
```

Comment: why have you ignored `tick` instance property from the original code :p

Comment: sure, that's one way to do it

Comment: I prefer this way Because it looks cleaner to me :) 
Constructor is meant to do initialization stuff and all ( Not only  )

Comment: I agree to some extent - though, I thought I'd fix the code as written, rather than rewrite it :p

Comment: Got it :) Cheers )